# Unable to use windows after installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my system. before that, i had windows 8. 

I did the alongside installation. after that, i can see the drives(& even the drive of windows) from within the Ubuntu. but i am unable to get the option of windows and Ubuntu at the boot menu.

I have tried my best to solve it.

- I have installed grub.
- I have gone through [Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), but i still unable to solve it.

can anyone help me?

my laptop model is- acer aspire v5- 5 series.

Comment: When you turn on your pc, what options do you have on Grub menu ?

Comment: Try boot repair and then post it's log.